# Flutter: Save image into directory not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to save an image choosen from gallery to the local device directory in Flutter.

**What I tried**

```
Future<void> _addPictureToGallery() async {
      final picker = ImagePicker();
      final imageFile =
          await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, maxWidth: 600);

      final appDir = await syspath.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      final fileName = path.basename(imageFile.path);

      final savedImage = await File(imageFile.path)
          .copy('${appDir.path}/albums/$albumID/$fileName');

      print(savedImage);

      picturesData.add(Picture(
          album: albumID,
          path: '${appDir.path}/albums/$albumID/$fileName'.toString(),
          timestamp: Timestamp.now()));
    }
```

But on `savedImage` I get the following error: `Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot copy file to '/Users/maxmuster/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE42E172-AC16-43FF-959A-6F2D17143416/data/Containers/Data/Application/33E8B35B-4C11-4A52-84FC-A7AA9EB75C62/Documents/albums/5/image_picker_569C41C6-0EBF-4EFA-A1D0-549FE1579801-32214-000011A2CD0B3A5F.jpg', path = '/Users/maxmuster/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/BE42E172-AC16-43FF-959A-6F2D17143416/data/Containers/Data/Application/33E8B35B-4C11-4A52-84FC-A7AA9EB75C62/tmp/image_picker_569C41C6-0EBF-4EFA-A1D0-549FE1579801-32214-000011A2CD0B3A5F.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`

What´s the issue here?

Comment: have you added write permisson?

Comment: Do I need? I´m testing with iOS device..

Comment: you can search this, there are lot of answer available

Comment: I have encountered this problem before, as you said, you need a real IOS device.